# Active record association in rails 4/5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following four models and I need help with how to associate the projects model to the timesheet and task model. The models I have are as follows:

```
User
Timesheet => has_many :tasks
Project => beloings_to :task
Project => has_many :tasks
Task => belongs_to :timesheet
Task=> belongs_to :project
```

When I execute the following association I get a response as shown below;

```
User.find(1).time_sheets.find(6).tasks
```

> [
> #<Task:0x00007fbdf5419780   id: 15,   description: "Fixed the mat issue",   task_date: "May 17, 2021",   hours_worked: 3,   project_id:
> 2,   created_at: Mon, 17 May 2021 16:57:28 UTC +00:00,   updated_at:
> Mon, 17 May 2021 16:57:28 UTC +00:00,   time_sheet_id: 6>,
> #<Task:0x00007fbdf54194b0   id: 16,   description: "Built IOS and Android module",   task_date: "May 17, 2021",   hours_worked: 3,
> project_id: 5,   created_at: Mon, 17 May 2021 23:41:00 UTC +00:00,
> updated_at: Mon, 17 May 2021 23:41:00 UTC +00:00,   time_sheet_id: 6>,
> ]

How do I associate the project model to the response and be able to be able to get the project_name in the result? Thanks for the help.